# Get Spring Boot 3 / Security 6 to clear the SecurityContext for a @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a Spring Boot 3.0 application that acts as a standard **oAuth2 ResourceServer**.

The service however also exposes one endpoint that should trigger an **OAuth2 login flow** (authorization code).

The use-case being that I need the user to login to another IDP so that I can fetch some claims from that idp token (using an oauth2 authorization code flow).

That particular oAuth2 flow is triggered via a `GetMapping` on a `RestController` that is triggered from the browser. Each time this GET request is executed, the oAuth2 login flow should be done and the user should have to authenticate again.

In **Spring Boot 2.7.8** I was using the following code to do that but this no longer works after moving to **Spring Boot 3.0**

```
@GetMapping("/start/oauth2Login")
public List<Map.Entry<String, Object>> start(OAuth2AuthenticationToken oAuth2AuthenticationToken, @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("oauth2-client") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {

// When this mapping is triggered, the oAuth2 authorization code flow is started,
// and when it is finished (after the user authenticated), 
// I end up here and can access the claims in the token


List<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entries = oAuth2AuthenticationToken
                .getPrincipal()
                .getAttributes()
                // some logic
                .toList();

SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

return entries;

}
```

Notice the `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();` near the end used to force Spring Boot to clear the `SecurityContext`, making sure the next time this endpoint is hit, the previous  `Authentication` object is cleared, and the user has to go through the oAuth2 dance again (as opposed to just entering this method again directly).

I believe this is caused by the [new session management introduced in Spring Security 6](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration/servlet/session-management.html), however I have been unable to come up with a proper fix.

Performing the `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();` already felt like a bit of a hack, so I was wondering what the proper solution would be.

Answer (score 1):

To me, this endpoint you expose is an OAuth2 client, not a resource-server. I address such needs as follow:

- add a dependency to spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client
- define a second security filter-chain bean for client configuration (the first being an existing one for resource-server) with

  - `securityMatcher` so that it applies only to client resources (login, logout and UI resources or your "special" endpoint)
  - higher @Order than the default filterchain (the on without `securityMatcher`)

With this solution, the security context for your "client" resources (built from regular session) will be separated from the security context for "resource-server" (built from the access-token).

I have just written a tutorial on this subject. See `resource-server_with_ui` available from [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).

Note that if you want the user to authenticate again each time he hits the "client" endpoint, you'll have to invalidate the session.

My first thought was creating a stateless client, but, as pointed by @ddewaele in the comments, this is stupid because the session is required for authorization-code flow to succeed.

Instead, you can just invalidate the session at the end of the controller method. At least two options for that:

- inject `HttpSession` as `@Controller` method param:

```java
@GetMapping("/start/oauth2Login") public List<Map.Entry<String, Object>> start(
        HttpSession session,
        OAuth2AuthenticationToken oAuth2AuthenticationToken,
        @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("oauth2-client") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
    ...
    session.invalidate();
    return entries;
}
```

- statically access the session bound to current request thread:

```java
@GetMapping("/start/oauth2Login")
public List<Map.Entry<String, Object>> start(
        OAuth2AuthenticationToken oAuth2AuthenticationToken,
        @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("oauth2-client") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
    ...
    Optional.ofNullable(RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
        .map(ServletRequestAttributes.class::cast)
        .map(ServletRequestAttributes::getRequest)
        .map(HttpServletRequest::getSession)
        .ifPresent(HttpSession::invalidate);
    return entries;
}
```

Please note that users are very likely to have a session on the authorization server too. If you want to prevent them from being auto-logged in after they are redirected there (with a "remember-me" cookie or whatever), you'll have to trigger a [RP-Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html): use an `OidcClientInitiated(Server)LogoutSuccessHandler` (or wrtie you own impl if the authorization-server does not expose an `end_session_endpoint` in its `.well-known/openid-configuration`). The tutorial linked above uses such a custom logout handler because Auth0 and Cognito do not follow the standard.

Comment: That separation is already the case here. Alongside the resourceServer filterChain bean there is also one for the .oauth2Login part. It is the "prevent the session from being saved " that is not working or not clear on how to approach. The oauth2 part works (both resource server part and oauth2 client part). It's forcing the user to login on each request for the oauth2 client that is not working. clearing the context worked in boot 2.7 but no longer in 3.0.

Comment: I've just edited to add details on that subject (be careful with the two distinct sessions: one on your client and another one on the authorization-server)

Comment: But I'm curious; why don't you want users to have sessions on that end-point (and save them the effort to login each time)?

Comment: on the endpoint we're discussing, the oAuth2 login / code flow is used to read out an ID card via OIDC (its not the ID card from the "logged in" user, but from somebody sitting next to the logged in user). The "logged in" user needs to capture the information from that card for a business flow. So the "user" in the oauth2 login flow is actually the ID card that we only need temporarily to read out some claims.  (was a bit too elaborate to put it in the question). (great tutorials by the way on github). But by caching the Authentication object, we were never able to read out a second card

Comment: Preventing session to be created on client is enough then, no need to logout from authorization-servers. Glad you like the tutorials, it is quite some work to write and maintain...

Comment: Problem is you need a session to do the oauth2 login dance

Comment: I updated my answer to replace the session disabling in the security conf with a static access to current request session to invalidate it. This code snippet is to insert in your `@Controller` method body. I'm sorry for my initial wrong answer: I keep on writing that sessions are required on OAuth2 clients, I don't know how I could think of such a solution :/